# How to bar plot with percentage of each bar

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have dataframe df with column x , column x have many values i want to plot bar . divde data in bins from 0 to 1  2to 3 ,4 to 5. each bin bar and percentage of each bar

i tried this now but i dont know how to give percentage of each bar

```
out = pd.cut(xz, bins=[0,1, 2, 6,], include_lowest=True)
ax = out.value_counts(sort=False).plot.bar(rot=0, color="b", figsize=(6,4))
```

Comment: change to `out.value_counts(normalize=True,sort=False)`

Comment: @ i am looking for annotate , each bin percentage should be on top of bar